# Train MS Custom Speech model to recognize dashed ids

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-platform

I want to enable my Microsoft Custom Speech model to recognize designators containing numbers, chars and dashes, something like this: `12-34 A-56 B78`.
The speech model recognizes numbers and characters correctly. Is there a way to train it so it would output the string `12-34 A-56 B78` when i say "twelve thirtyfour a fiftysix b seventyeight"? I need this for a german speech model.

I've already tried to train a model with `10000` randomly generated strings like the one above. I then trained the model using related text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using live Speech to text, or batch transcription?

Comment: I use live speech to text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are very specific format requirements. Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to get results exactly like this from the speech service. I suggest to do some post-processing on the results to format them this way.